# MongoDB+Spring: Search by text @Query

Tags: java, spring, mongodb, mongodb-query

Working with MongoDB + Spring + MongoRepository I wanted to make a query by text as the MongoDB documentation shows.

I adapted the code:

```
db.users.find({ $text: { $search: "xxxxx"}});
```

To:

```
@Query("{'$text':{'$search':?0}}")
List<User> findBySearchText(String searchText);
```

I guess is correct. But the console showed me that I have to index the fields I wanted to use (@TextIndexed). So I did it.

Console still complaining with multiple errors cause I have a principal 'POJO' with more 'POJO' pending of the principal. Any help? Tried to put the inside POJOS as new collections with they corresponding fields indexed :

```
 exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'userRepository': Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is com.mongodb.CommandFailureException: { "serverUsed" : "localhost:27017" , "createdCollectionAutomatically" : true , "numIndexesBefore" : 1 , "errmsg" : "exception: bad index key pattern { personalInformation.mobilePhone: \"text\", personalInformation.phone: \"text\", personalInformation.nif: \"text\", personalInformation.address: \"text\", personalInformation.population._id: \"text\", personalInformation.population.name: \"text\", personalInformation.population.fatherId: \"text\", personalInformation.population.provinceId: \"text\", personalInformation.town._id: \"text\", personalInformation.town.name: \"text\", personalInformation.town.fatherName: \"text\", personalInformation.postalCode: \"text\", personalInformation.censusPopulation._id: \"text\", professionalExperiences.toYear: \"text\",  
complementaryInformation.languages._id: \"text\", complementaryInformation.languages.name: \"text\", complementaryInformation.languages.readLevel: \"text\", complementaryInformation.languages.wroteLevel: \"text\", complementaryInformation.languages.spokeLevel: \"text\", complementaryInformation.ownCar: \"text\", professionalPreferences._id: \"text\", professionalPreferences.profession._id: \"text\", professionalPreferences.profession.value: \"text\", professionalPreferences.job._id: \"text\", professionalPreferences.job.value: \"text\", followPreference.serviceGuidance: \"text\", followPreference.serviceBusinessAdvice: \"text\" }: Index key pattern too large." , "code" : 67 , "ok" : 0.0}
```

Comment: Can you post your IndexDefintion ? The Error states something is wrong with that definition (`Index key pattern too large`).

Comment: I found that I've indexed wrong. I putted the indexed annotation on the POJOS definition instead of the attributes of them. Changing that I've found another error...what can I do to index attributes with the same composition? For instances... private MapData hand; private MapData toe ...where 'MapData' is  public class MapData {

 private String id;
 private String value;

 public MapData() {

 }

Comment: You should articulate this as a separate question. Including the relevant code snippets and , very important, error message.